# How to sum a matrix cell value into another by row/column names?

Tags: r, matrix

Imagine I have an overall list of authors

```
Authors <- c("Abel","Babel","Cain","Devil","Esau")
```

with it I build an overall adjacency matrix, initialized with zeroes

```
allAuthors <- matrix(0L,nrow=length(Authors),ncol=length(Authors),dimnames=list(Authors,Authors))
```

now I am stumbling on  a paper coAuthored by these three guys

```
paperAuthors <- c("Babel","Cain","Devil")
```

and build another adjacency matrix of their collaboration, initialized with all 1s

```
coAuth <- matrix(1L,nrow=length(paperAuthors),ncol=length(paperAuthors),dimnames=list(paperAuthors,paperAuthors))
```

## Question :

How do I sum the coAuth matrix cell values into the corresponding allAuthors
matrix cells using the row and colum names as indices ?

In other words I'd like to obtain the cells of the allAuthors matrix having 1s at the intersection of the paperAuthors authors while all other remain 0s.

## Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we get the indexes in the `coAuth` matrix.

```
ind <- which(coAuth == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)
```

Now we have to find the corresponding indexes in the `allAuthors` matrix.

```
ind.allAuthors <- cbind(
    match(rownames(coAuth), rownames(allAuthors))[ind[, 'row']],
    match(colnames(coAuth), colnames(allAuthors))[ind[, 'col']])
```

And now we can sum the elements from both matrices:

```
allAuthors[ind.allAuthors] <- allAuthors[ind.allAuthors] + 1
```

Comment: Moltes gràcies @ernest-a ! Your approach works well even though in my ignorance I find the other answer from Plamen Petrov simpler to understand and code!

Comment: De res! My answer uses a matrix as an index, which lets you select arbitrary elements from a matrix/array. Plamen's answer uses vector indexes, which are simpler but they only let you select a rectangular area. Look here for an explanation: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Array-indexing

Answer (score 0):

Would subsetting work for your needs or do you need to define new matrix summation operation?

```
allAuthors[paperAuthors, paperAuthors] <- 
  allAuthors[paperAuthors, paperAuthors] + 1
allAuthors
```

Comment: Thank you very much @plamenpetrov your solutions seem to work well even in the case the coauthors are not in adjacent spaces in the overall matrix!

Comment: Hi Plamen, while your example worked flawlessly for the example I gave, in my real life situation for reasons I cannot grasp it did not work, while the other solution did. Thank you so much for your help which taught me something about this fantastic but also beginner unfriendly language :-)